# How do they film scenes with storms?

Tags: effects

In some movies, such as *Equalizer 2*, for example, there are scenes that take place in storms or hurricanes. How do they create such scenes? It would seem to be difficult to fake whole streets being blown by 60-mile-an-hour winds.

Comment: It probably varies but there are significant rain and wind machines that can be used to create in-camera driving rain. Combined with lighting and sound, and these days a CGI sky, that can go a long way. https://jmfx.net/products

Answer (score 2):

Creating this type of movie is challenging because in not making it look extremely cheesy the director is forced to use as many practical effects as possible. Of course, there is also the aspect of making the weather look good, to give the viewer this feeling of monumentality where real tornados and other extreme weather conditions are hard to capture from up close or hard to make look good on camera. For the inside of a tornado or up-close shots CGI is mostly used. For shots from the distance both real or CGI versions of the tornado are used.

There are clips about making this kind of movie.

Making of Twister from 1996

Ocean storm sequence from a TV commercial

Comment: The making of video of Twister is very long and talks about a lot of subjects unrelated to the question at hand. Perhaps you can link to a couple timecodes where they talk about weather effects specifically?